# Interesting approximation of distribution of numbers in a Farey sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, approximation, farey-sequences

I was investigating the distribution of the numbers in a [Farey sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farey_sequence) and found some pattern.

It is known that the [number of elements in Farey sequence](http://oeis.org/A005728) can be found using Euler totient function. So let the number of elements in the Farey sequence of order $n$ be $\left | F_n \right |$.

Also let's divide the [0, 1] number line into intervals: $(0; \frac{1}{n}]$, $(\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n - 1}]$, $(\frac{1}{n-1}, \frac{1}{n - 2}]$, ..., $(\frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{2}]$, $(\frac{1}{2}, 1]$ and count the number of elements in each interval.

If one will take intervals in a reverse order ($(\frac{1}{2}, 1]$ is the first one, $(\frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{2}]$ is the second and so on) I found that number of elements in the first interval is exactly half of the $\left | F_n \right |$. This is not really exciting and easy to prove seeing that elements in the sequence are symmetrical around $1/2$.

What I found surprising is that the number of elements in each other interval is approximately equal to $\frac{\left | F_n \right |}{6}$, $\frac{\left | F_n \right |}{12}$, $\frac{\left | F_n \right |}{20}$, $\frac{\left | F_n \right |}{30}$, $\frac{\left | F_n \right |}{42}$.

---

Which brings me to a **hypothesis that the number of elements in the i-th interval from the right is approximately equal to**:

$$\frac{\left | F_n \right |}{i \cdot (i + 1)}$$

Which sounds kind of correct, because if I will add the elements in all intervals, I will get:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n }\frac{\left | F_n \right |}{i \cdot (i + 1)} = \left | F_n \right |\sum_{i=1}^{n }\frac{1}{i \cdot (i + 1)}=\left | F_n \right |\cdot (1 - \frac{1}{n + 1})\approx \left | F_n \right |$$

---

I have a couple of questions:

- where can I read more information about this approximation (I assume that someone has studied it)?
- is there a way to calculate precisely* the number of elements in each interval (or is there a way to prove "my" approximation)?

P.S.* I know that I can calculate the numbers by generating all the elements in the sequence and then going through each of them and checking which interval it belongs to (this is how I found the hypothesis). The problem is that the sequence grows quadratically and takes to much time. So I am looking for a way to calculate the numbers without generating the sequence.

Answer (score 4):

Your "hypothesis" is actually an evidence of the fact that Farey sequence is uniformly distributed in $[0,1]$, which means that for every subinterval $I$ of $[0,1]$ we have $\frac{|F_n \cap I|}{|F_n|} = |I|$ for $n \to \infty$ (here $|I|$ denotes the length of the interval $I$, i.e., the upperbound minus the lowerbound). In your case, the lengths of the subintervals are of the form $\frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{k+1}$, which is indeed $\frac{1}{k(k+1)}$.

This is one of the interesting aspects of Farey fractions, which, as some papers say, has a close connection to Riemann Hypothesis. Unfortunately the proof(s) seems to require advanced knowledge. This paper http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PID=GDZPPN002307634, on page 341-342, suggests some references which contain the proof(s).

If anybody could nicely explain the outline of the proof(s), and also the connection of this to Riemann Hypothesis, in a plain language, I would like to know too. :)